# in QTP, how to check whether a dialog is already open?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I have been using the following code to check whether a dialog is already open

```
If  Window(window_name).Dialog(dialog_name).Exist = False 
    Then '' //here qtp waits..
    Window(window_name).WinMenu("Menu").Select menu_name
End If
```

This code is to avoid reopening the same dialog during each run of the code. But the qtp run waits about 10 - 15 seconds & then goes to next step. in what way we can avoid this?

If the dialog is not open, then the menu will be clicked to open the dialog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Exist` property accepts a value of how long to wait for the object to exist.

```
If Window(window_name).Dialog(dialog_name).Exist(60) = False
```

Comment: BTW, you can use the logical `Not` operator instead of comparing to `False`: `If Not Window(window_name).Dialog(dialog_name).Exist(60) Then ...`.

Answer (score 0):

The method mentioned is good. You can also try this method.

```
If (Window(window_name).Dialog(dialog_name)
  .winbutton(Btn_name).Getroproperty("abs_x"))
```

This returns true if the object exists if not it returns false.